# Number ordered list and re-ordering c#

Tags: c#

I have an ordered list in a DB lets say:

Name Order

John 1

Mary 2

Sarah 3

Peter 4

A user can change the order and in the front end I have a simple for loop which is built based on the number of items in the model list. So:

```
<select name="order" class="form-control textarea">
    @for (int io = 1; io <= Model.Count; io++)
    {
        if (io == i.Order)
        {
            <option value="@io" selected="selected">@io</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@io">@io</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

However, when the user changes the selected option for lets say Sarah from 3 to 1. and saves the record, how best can I re-order the existing records so that they then resemble the following in C# in my Controller?

Name Order

Sarah 1

John 2

Mary 3

Peter 4

I've tried a remove and insertat in a list on the data but my numbering went haywire.

Comment: iOrder is the order of item as per the DB at runtime. the Select is contained within a parent ForEach of the model records. hence if the io value equals the i.Order value, its set as selected.

Comment: Is it acceptable to update the `Order` value of all elements after `Sarah`? (Is the list of people small enough for this to be reasonable?) If so, you could just set `Sarah`'s `Order` to `i` and increment all following (`i`th and up) people's `Order`. This is just like inserting an element into a list: you need to shift the rest of the elements down then place the new element into the right spot.

Comment: it may not help you, but when I do something similar to this, I expose the order ID value to the user with a message to encourage them to use large numbers, such as 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. It's then much harder to cause a collision.

Comment: @31eee384 that's exactly what ive done to get this working for now.

Comment: @AndyJones Cool! What would you want to improve on that solution? If it's fine you can post a self-answer or if not make an edit with the way you're doing it now and what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is completely server side code. Once it is rendered, you no longer have access to any of those variables.

There are a couple of options, but all of them require some javascript.

1. You could refresh the page with the new data.
2. You could call a server method that would return a new sorted list.
3. You would use JavaScript to sort the new data.

Comment: I'm aware that it needs to be server side, probably should have said it's when the user saves the new order it needs to update the others in the DB, is being done in my controller code.